# How to find an index of the first matching element in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking for a TensorFlow way of implementing something similar to Python's list.index() function.

Given a matrix and a value to find, I want to know the first occurrence of the value in each row of the matrix.

For example,

```
m is a <batch_size, 100> matrix of integers
val = 23

result = [0] * batch_size
for i, row_elems in enumerate(m):
  result[i] = row_elems.index(val)
```

I cannot assume that 'val' appears only once in each row, otherwise I would have implemented it using tf.argmax(m == val). In my case, it is important to get the index of the *first* occurrence of 'val' and not any.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems that `tf.argmax` works like [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) (according to [the test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/argmax_op_test.py#L67)), which will return the first index when there are multiple occurrences of the max value.
You can use `tf.argmax(tf.cast(tf.equal(m, val), tf.int32), axis=1)` to get what you want. However, currently the behavior of `tf.argmax` is undefined in case of multiple occurrences of the max value.

If you are worried about undefined behavior, you can apply `tf.argmin` on the return value of `tf.where` as @Igor Tsvetkov suggested.
For example,

```
# test with tensorflow r1.0
import tensorflow as tf

val = 3
m = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
m_feed = [[0  ,   0, val,   0, val],
          [val,   0, val, val,   0],
          [0  , val,   0,   0,   0]]

tmp_indices = tf.where(tf.equal(m, val))
result = tf.segment_min(tmp_indices[:, 1], tmp_indices[:, 0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result, feed_dict={m: m_feed})) # [2, 0, 1]
```

Note that `tf.segment_min` will raise `InvalidArgumentError` when there is some row containing no `val`. In your code `row_elems.index(val)` will raise exception too when `row_elems` don't contain `val`.

Comment: This is very helpful! what if we wanted to update val to become a new_val?  I asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684445/tensorflow-update-first-matching-element-in-each-row

Comment: The TF documentation on `argmax` specifically states: "Note that in case of ties the identity of the return value is not guaranteed." Which leads me to believe that you can't rely on `argmax` returning the first value like numpy does, which I suspect is because of non-deterministic behavior on distributed devices like GPUs.

Comment: Since TF 2.3, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.3/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax) for `tf.argmax` *does* guarantee that "*In case of identity returns the smallest index.*"

Answer (score 4):

Looks a little ugly but works (assuming `m` and `val` are both tensors):

```python
idx = list()
for t in tf.unpack(m, axis=0):
    idx.append(tf.reduce_min(tf.where(tf.equal(t, val))))
idx = tf.pack(idx, axis=0)
```

**EDIT:**
As [Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419116/yaroslav-bulatov) mentioned, you could achieve the same result with `tf.map_fn`:

```python
def index1d(t):
    return tf.reduce_min(tf.where(tf.equal(t, val)))

idx = tf.map_fn(index1d, m, dtype=tf.int64)
```

Comment: `map_fn` can do it without unpacking

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution to the problem, assuming there is a hit on every row.

```
import tensorflow as tf

val = 3
m = tf.constant([
    [0  ,   0,   val,   0, val],
    [val,   0,   val, val,   0],
    [0  , val,     0,   0,   0]])

# replace all entries in the matrix either with its column index, or out-of-index-number
match_indices = tf.where(                          # [[5, 5, 2, 5, 4],
    tf.equal(val, m),                              #  [0, 5, 2, 3, 5],
    x=tf.range(tf.shape(m)[1]) * tf.ones_like(m),  #  [5, 1, 5, 5, 5]]
    y=(tf.shape(m)[1])*tf.ones_like(m))

result = tf.reduce_min(match_indices, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result)) # [2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which also considers the case the element is not included by the matrix (solution from github repository of DeepMind)

```
def get_first_occurrence_indices(sequence, eos_idx):
    '''
    args:
        sequence: [batch, length]
        eos_idx: scalar
    '''
    batch_size, maxlen = sequence.get_shape().as_list()
    eos_idx = tf.convert_to_tensor(eos_idx)
    tensor = tf.concat(
            [sequence, tf.tile(eos_idx[None, None], [batch_size, 1])], axis = -1)
    index_all_occurrences = tf.where(tf.equal(tensor, eos_idx))
    index_all_occurrences = tf.cast(index_all_occurrences, tf.int32)
    index_first_occurrences = tf.segment_min(index_all_occurrences[:, 1], 
index_all_occurrences[:, 0])
    index_first_occurrences.set_shape([batch_size])
    index_first_occurrences = tf.minimum(index_first_occurrences + 1, maxlen)
    
    return index_first_occurrences
```

And:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mat = tf.Variable([[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,5,6,7], [0,0,0,0,0]], dtype = tf.int32)
idx = 3
first_occurrences = get_first_occurrence_indices(mat, idx)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(first_occurrence) # [3, 2, 1, 5]
```