# Get the index from tensor tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
all_max = tf.convert_to_tensor([[4, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=tf.float32)
```

How to get the index of the element `[3,4,5]` from the tensor array `all_max`?

In list, we simply use `list.index(element)` to get the index for an element present in list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found this on : https://www.py4u.net/discuss/147615
worked for me

To find element index of a 2d/3d tensor covert it into 1d
#ie example.view(number of elements)

Example:

```
mat=torch.tensor([[1,2],[4,3])
#to find index of 2
five = 2
mat=mat.view(4)
numb_of_col = 4
for o in range(numb_of_col):
   if mat[o] == five:
   print(torch.tensor([o]))
```

Comment: @vishakraj check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/42190780/13319197

Comment: @vishakraj i hope it help you